# How to code a diet reminder in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, nstimer, reminders

I'm trying to code an app that reminds me to hit a certain diet goal (drink 8 glasses of water, eat two fruits, take vitamins etc)

The problem is if I code these as reminders using local notifications, I don't get to execute code. So I can't adjust the reminders every hour relative to my goal. For example don't show the reminder if I already hit the goal. Or say stop the reminder past dinner time and start again in the morning.

If I code these as NSTimer the problem is they don't run in the background.

I suppose I can move all the logic to a server and use push notification instead. But this is huge amount of work for what I would consider a very simple self reminder app.

What is the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

> if I code these as reminders using local notifications, I don't get to execute code

I use a pill-taking app, and it does use local notifications. The local notification does let the app execute code, if the user taps / swipes (whatever) the notification. The app then puts up a dialog where I enter what actually happened (I took the pill, I skipped it, etc.).

The app simply assumes that if the user doesn't respond and tell it what happened, then nothing happened (i.e. the user missed the pill). How does it know that? Well, as with any local notification-based timer app, the app must maintain an internal list of pending events. It strikes a pending event from the list when it knows the outcome. That way, if the app is not running and then it *is* running, it can look back over its list and note that there are past pending events, thus proving that the user failed to respond to a reminder.

Comment: local notification execution will work for keeping count as a result of user action, but it won't work for logic that is based on time. For example, stop reminding after 7pm because you are not supposed to be consuming this item in the evening. Or even just during sleeping time. How does your app work? Does it keep bugging you while sleeping?

Comment: "local notification execution will work for keeping count as a result of user action, but it won't work for logic that is based on time" Correct; that is exactly what I'm telling you! Logic based on time is the business logic of your app, and it is internal to and up to your app. The local notifications are just a way of communicating with the user. But they have the great advantage that they are stored with the _system_, which is always running — whereas your app is not. Thus, they can remind when your app is not running, which is most of the time.